How to declare a global variable and keep it updated across multiple files/classes?
Purpose is to keep the same settings for my whole program.
When the program runs, it should read some text files (user edited) and overwrite the corresponding global variables. The unedited ones should keep a default value.
I'm currently doing this using two separate files: Settings.h and DefaultSettings.h
In Settings.h:
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace Settings {
   extern int bits;
   extern int k;
   extern int nsym;

   extern void apply_settings(std::string &name, std::string &value);
}

In DefaultSettings.h:
#pragma once
#include "Settings.h"
#include <string>
namespace Settings {
   int bits = 8;
   int k = 20;
   int nsym = 12;

   // Called one by one by the file reader
   void apply_settings(std::string &name, std::string &value) {
        if (name == "bits") {
           bits = atoi(value.c_str());
        } else if (name == "k") {
           k = atoi(value.c_str());
        } else if (name == "nsym") {
           nsym = atoi(value.c_str());
        }
   }
}

Later in the program, after reading and applying the settings, I create the class instances and use it like this:
#pragma once
#include "Settings.h"

class RSCodec {
    int bits, k, nsym;
    public:
        RSCodec();
        virtual ~RSCodec();
};

And in the cpp file
#include "RSCodec.h"

RSCodec::RSCodec() {
    bits = Settings::bits;
    k = Settings::k;
    nsym = Settings::nsym;

    printf("BITS %d, K %d, NSYM %d\n", bits, k, nsym);
}

RSCodec::~RSCodec() {}

Always outputs the default values instead of the updated ones.
Some other classes seem to work with the updated values instead, but it's accessed in the same way (just different namespaces, like Settings::RF24::, Settings::DUAL_RF24::, etc)
Minimal example:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "DefaultSettings.h"
#include "RSCodec.h"

int main() {

    string k = "k";
    string nsym = "nsym";
    string val = "10";

    Settings::apply_settings(k, val);
    Settings::apply_settings(nsym, val);

    RSCodec* rsc = new RSCodec();

    return 0;
}

In my program, k would still be the default value (20) instead of the new one (10)

Using globals is not a good idea. Either pass the shared config to your various modules, or as a last resort use the singleton pattern.

I don't think this is a [mcve].

Also, what is the current output and how does it differ from your expected output?

I've edited the question.
Also, this is basically a shared config, just not enclosed in a class or struct. All other classes already know where it is in memory (Settings.h).
The singleton idea works, I'd just prefer to avoid changing the whole project if it is supposed to work this way too

You really should lookup "dependency injection".   RSCodec* rsc = new RSCodec(); is a useless use of new. So : Make Settings a local variable in main (and ideally give it an abstract baseclass with getter/setter pure virtual functions).  Call the baseclass ISettings (because it is an interface) and then add a constructor to RSCodec, RSCodec(ISettings& setting) to pass your settings to the codec. That's dependency injection and it will make your code better for testing/maintainability/refactoring

Turns out the minimal example I provided does in fact work.
I just forgot to call apply_settings for all my namespaces in the file reader.

I would recommend closing as a typo in this case

#include 
using namespace std;
#include "DefaultSettings.h"
#include "RSCodec.h"
int main() {
string k = "k";
string nsym = "nsym";
string val = "10";

Settings::apply_settings(k, val);
Settings::apply_settings(nsym, val);

RSCodec* rsc = new RSCodec();

return 0;

}
